# Disassembling WPF4 beta2 DLLs with Reflector

Tags: wpf, reflector, disassembly

I'm trying to disassemble some of the DLL of the new WPF4 Beta2 framework. However, all I have is empty methods for all types. I'm not having this problem for other DLL (for example mscorlib).

Do you have any idea what is causing this behavior ? Is this anything to do with type forwarding (I know that some WPF types have moved in System.Xaml.dll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found the problem (however I don't really understand it...), I was not using the right DLL.

I was using DLL in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0 whereas I should use C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\WPF

Comment: Those assemblies are "metadata only" versions used by Visual Studio for performance and multitargeting purposes only.  They don't contain any actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I personally am not sure, but Red-Gate does have a group they watch for Reflector:http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewforum.php?f=85 you might try posting there if you don't hear anything back soon.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the problem is the fact that this relies on some of the new features of .NET 4.0. Support for these has just been added to the latest early access build of Reflector, which you can download from here:

http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=10835